# How to capture paste event in c++

Tags: c++, winapi, clipboard, paste

I know I can capture **copy** event by adding the windows handle to the clipboard viewer chain using the `SetClipboardViewer` or by having a hook to the keyboard.

But there seems to be no clipboard message propagated when **paste** occurs (either using ctrl+v, right-click->paste or menu edit->paste.

Is there any other way we can capture the paste event?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a dupe because the other question is about blocking a paste.  We don't know why this question wants to detect a paste.  I was mid-answer when the question was closed.  What I'd written is: "There is no real paste event that you can hook.  Pasting is something individual applications _might_ do when they access data that's on the clipboard.  Since some apps access data on the clipboard for other reasons, there's no way for the system to know when a paste has occurred."

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: The other question is about both *detecting* and *blocking* a paste. The answer I gave to that question regarding detection applies equally to this question, too. That is why I marked this as a duplicate. The answer you were writing would equally apply to the other question, too

Comment: @RemyLebeau I cant find the other question you are talking about. Would you mind sharing the link?

Comment: @ShameelMohamed It was linked when I closed this question as a duplicate, which has since been reversed. Here is the link: [Clipboard viewer doesn't get paste notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46699066/)

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthyThank you for the response. But there would be some means to achieve this. To capture the paste event.

Comment: There isn't. An application could read clipboard contents in response to a custom button press. Or no user interaction altogether. Unless you are prepared to hook all system calls pertaining to reading the clipboard, there isn't much you can do about it. This bears the question: Why do you think you need to be notified about clipboard read access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct, you can't detect paste by viewing clipboard.
Copy to clipboard are write operations, you see in your clipboard viewer (though you can't distinguish them from cut).

Paste from clipboard are read operations, so you don't see them in clipboard viewer, and even if you did, you could not distinguish paste and previewing in "paste special" without actual pasting.

Globally monitoring WM_PASTE might help. For example with Notepad you should see it with both Ctrl+V paste and context menu paste. But some applications won't use this message - they are not obliged to.